# How to transfer data from one table to another by increasinf the primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table like following -

```
COLOR

    colorId name description
    1000    White White
    1001    Blue  Blue

 ProductFeature
productFeatureId productFeatureTypeId description
20001            COLOR                White
20002            COLOR                Blue
```

In color table I have almost 400 rows. Now I am trying to write a sql query to transfer those rows into ProductFeature table by telling that productFeatureTypeId="COLOR" and the productFeatureId(primary key) will be incremented every time.

Comment: Add auto_increment to the id column

Comment: Unfortunately (or perhaps fortunately) colour is an edge case. Colours are, by their nature, uniquely identifiable.

Answer (score 0):

Create the product table with this structure,

```
CREATE TABLE ProductFeature (
     productFeatureId MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     productFeatureTypeId CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     description CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (productFeatureId)
)
```

EDIT : If table is already present, alter the datatype of that column, in your case change first remove all the values present in productFeatureid field and alter datatype as auto_increment

```
ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY <column_name> <type> ;
```

Comment: table is already created..I am trying to transfer all colors from COLOR to PRODUCT_FEATURE

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `productFeatureId` has `AUTO_INCREMENT`, you can use the `insert into ... select` statement.

```
insert into ProductFeature (productFeatureTypeId, description) 
    select 'COLOR', name from Color;
```

Comment: Actually i m looking for a stored procedure..My MySql does not auto increment the primary key field..